# How to evaluate specific dates between two given dates

Tags: r

I have 2 dates and a frequency. Take the final date, and go back 12/frequency months, until the resultant date it's less than the starting date. (Below example #1).

I have a code, and works but it's slow because make use of while loop.
Also have a exception for example: if the day of final date is the last day of month, then all the other dates should be as well the last day of the corresponding month. But my code don't do this last part. (Below example #2)

```
cpdatesfun<- function(sdate, fdate, frq = 2){
  m <- month(fdate) 
  y <- year(fdate) 
  d <- day(fdate) 
  cp <- fdate 
  dcp <- c()# null
while (as.numeric(cp - sdate)>=0) { #Kind of recursive 
  dcp <- ymd(dcp, cp)
  y = ifelse(m-12/frq <= 0,y-1, y)
  m = ifelse(m-12/frq <= 0, 12 + m-12/frq, m-12/frq)
  dm <- days_in_month(make_date(year = y, month = m, day = 1))
  d = ifelse(dm<d, dm,d)
  cp <- make_date(year = y, month = m, day = d) 
  }
  return(sort(dcp))
}

cpdatesfun(dmy(150119), dmy(200220)) #Example #1 good
cpdatesfun(dmy(150119), dmy(280220)) # Example #2 wrong
```

[1] "2019-02-20" "2019-08-20" "2020-02-20"
[1] "2019-02-28" "2019-08-28" "2020-02-28"

The right result in Example#2 should be
[1] "2019-02-28" "2019-08-31" "2020-02-28"

I want a faster way than using while loop, and get the right dates in case of month end.

Comment: Hey could you provide data as a minimally reproducible example and also what is your code intended to do.

Comment: Sure, I have updated it

Comment: Is `sdate` the start date?

Comment: Also will this only go as far back as 12 months? If not, that changes the problem.

Comment: I just made a better explanation, hoping some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in base R called `seq.Date` which can take a start date and end date and create a vector of dates. Now to put it into a function you can try doing:

```
cpdatesfun <- function(sdate, fdate, frq = 2){
   require(lubridate)
   kdate <- ceiling_date(as.Date(fdate), unit = "month") - days(1)
   sdate <- as.Date(sdate)
   newdate <- kdate - years(1)
   vec_date <- seq.Date(newdate, kdate, length.out = frq+1)
   fin_date <- vec_date[which(vec_date >= sdate)]
   return(fin_date)
}
```

Let me know how this goes: I may need to make a correction.